# How to process response using jquery-steps?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-steps

I am new to jquery/ajax and have a template that uses jquery-steps.  How do I read/process a json response from the server after the form has submitted?
I know how to do it in a basic form with the following by calling the showResponse function:

```
var options = { 
    dataType:           'json',    
    success:            showResponse,  // post-submit callback      
}; 
$('#form').ajaxForm(options);
```

But I am unable to get this integrated with the jquery-steps plugin which goes something like this:

```
$("#form").steps({
     bodyTag: "fieldset",
     onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
     {
      ...............

     },
     onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
     {
     ...........

     },
     onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
     {
      ........

     },

     onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
     {
          var form = $(this);

           // Submit form input
           form.submit();
      }
}).validate({
      errorPlacement: function (error, element)
      {
            element.before(error);
       },
       rules: {
              confirm: {
                      equalTo: "#password"
              }
        }
  });
```

Basically, I need help to be able to call the "showResponse" function after the form is submitted.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all I needed to do was to call $('#form').ajaxForm(options); 
It wasn't working earlier because I forgot to include the .js in the header.